# C# Winform close opened window when call other window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How can I close an opened window when I call a new window? That means I want only 1 child window at the time. I don't allow multi-window.

```
public partial class Main_Usr : Form
    {
        public Main_Usr()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;

            if (Program.IsFA) barSubItem_Ordre.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemVisibility.Never;

            Ordre_Liste f = new Ordre_Liste();
            f.MdiParent = this;
            f.Show();
   }

        private void barButtonItem_CreateOrdre_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Program.AllerRetour = "Ordre Aller";
            Ordre_Fiche f = new Ordre_Fiche();
            f.MdiParent = this;
            f.Show();
        }

        private void barButtonItem_OrdreListe_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Ordre_Liste f = new Ordre_Liste();
            f.MdiParent = this;
            f.Show();
        }

        private void barButtonItem_CreateOrdRet_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Program.AllerRetour = "Ordre Retour";
            Ordre_Fiche f = new Ordre_Fiche();
            f.MdiParent = this;
            f.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: on each itemclick dispose the other child windows.

Comment: Why are you using MDI window for displaying only one child? Use simple window and display different controls inside that window, or try using 'TabControl`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky i use that for implementing pseudo WebForm Master page. i know there NO master page in WinForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to implement pseudo masterpage:

- You can create BaseForm form with desired layout. Then inherit other forms from this BaseForm and provide custom content.
- You can create MainForm form with desired layout. Then create content controls as UserControls and show them in panel.
- You can create MasterUserControl with desired layout. Then create content controls by inheriting from MasterUserControl (they will have same layout). Then use your main form as browser for displaying different content controls like pages.

EXAMPLE:

1. Create desired layout on `Main_Usr` form.
2. Do not set it as MdiContainer
3. If you want to access some controls (e.g. footer or header from child forms, set property `Modifiers` of those controls to protected)
4. Open `Ordre_Liste` form code and change it to inherit from `Main_Usr` form, instead of `Form`
5. Add custom content to `Ordre_Liste` form

voila! you have 'masterpage'

UPDATE (for 3rd option)

1. Create new user control with name `MasterUserControl`
2. Create desired layout on this control, keeping space for custom content (btw don't use TableLayoutPanels - they have issue with designer inheritance).
3. Create new user control with name `HomeUserControl` and change it to inherit from your `MasterUserControl`.
4. Open `HomeUserControl` designer and add custom content. Also you can modify parent controls, which has `protected` modifier.
5. On your main form place `HomePageUserControl`

There different ways to implement navigation between controls (aka pages). Simplest way - have menu on main form. Other way - define event 'Navigate' on master control, subscribe to that event on main form, and raise it from 'pages'.

Comment: Thanks you...but which one is better the 1 or 2 way ?

Comment: With first way you have to deal with different forms. With second way its hard to update 'masterpage' controls from child. I think best approach here is 3rd way - creating 'masterpage' UserControl. And inheriting other controls from it (they will have same layout). Then switching this controls inside your main form, like changing pages inside browser.

Answer (score 1):

Create Form instances on a class level.
Then you can access to them from events or methods.

```
    Form1 f1;
    Form2 f2;

void OpenForm1()
{
    f1 = new Form1()
    f1.Show();
}

void OpenForm2()
{
    f1.Dispose(); //or Hide if you want to show it again later
    f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response, that mean i have to dispose 1 by 1. is there any posibility to dispose all form that opened

Comment: You can loop through opened forms to close them.

Comment: @user609511 Keep all of the forms in a List or Array so that you can iterate it and then close them.

Answer (score 0):

Like:

```
List<Form> openForms = new List<Form>();

foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    openForms.Add(f);

foreach (Form f in openForms)
{
    if (f.Name != "Menu")
        f.Close();
}
```

Note, do NOT close them directly, becuase there will come to an error, if you would try to close (or dispose) them in the 1st foreach loop. Thats why you need to put them into a list and close them there.